# What is the proper date and time format for ordering rows in MySQL/PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, sql-order-by

I'm trying to `SELECT` rows from a MySQL table and order them by date and time:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY post_date DESC");
```

The `post_date` is formatted as such: **2012-07-18 01:52:57am  (o-m-d h:i:sa)**. I figured that this was the proper simple date format, however it isn't sorting accurately.

Ex Output:

1.) 2012-07-18 12:41:07am

2.) 2012-07-18 12:26:03am

3.) 2012-07-18 01:52:57am

As you can see the most recent post at 1:52 is at the bottom when it should be at the top. What the heck am I doing wrong and what is the correct date and time format?

Comment: The field data type is date-time. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is treating 12>1 ..better use 24 hrs format without am/pm

Answer (score 1):

Are you storing `post_date` as a string?  There is a `datetime` type (also `timestamp`, probably preferred for something like the post date).  If you can change to these types, it will work better.

Otherwise, you'll have to stort them in php using something like `strtotime`:

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $results[strtotime($row['post_date'])] = $row;
}
ksort($results);
```

This is the simplest solution, but it also requires that no timestamps are the same.

Comment: no. `post_date` is already stored. Can you give me an example with strtotime?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `user` 
ORDER BY cast(post_date as datetime) DESC
```

Comment: This didn't work, the output was the same. What is this suppose to do?

Comment: If you stored it as string that would have converted it to a `datetime`. But looking at your example data I think it sorts correct. Isn't `12:41:07am` equal to `00:41:07`? `pm` means past midday. since it is `12` it can only be right after midnight, right?